# Subtract two time mysql

Tags: mysql

I am trying to subtract my column varchar from `24:00`

I am trying to use this query:

```
datediff(Hour, "20:00", hour1)
```

Example if `hour1 = 12:30` then the expected output is `8:30`

Comment: `12:30` is `7:30` from `20:00` or `11:30` from `24:00`...

Answer (score 1):

Use this for subtracting '12:30' from a date

```
DATE_SUB(`date`,INTERVAL '12:30' HOUR_MINUTE)

DATE_SUB('2019-02-01 20:00:00',INTERVAL '12:30' HOUR_MINUTE)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`TIME_TO_SEC`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_time-to-sec) to convert your time into a number of seconds, subtract it from `24:00` and then use [`SEC_TO_TIME`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_sec-to-time) to convert back to a time and then [`TIME_FORMAT`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_time-format) to format it as hours:minutes

e.g.

```
SET @hour1 = '12:30'
SELECT TIME_FORMAT(SEC_TO_TIME(TIME_TO_SEC('24:00')-TIME_TO_SEC(@hour1)), '%H:%i')
```

Output:

```
11:30
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.2&fiddle=d0a2193de43e7528c452a3ce921b699e)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
select TIMEDIFF('20:00',str_to_date(hour1,'%H:%i')) from tablename;
```